# How can I exclude node_modules with typedoc?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, typedoc

There is the scripts in package.json:

```
    "scripts": {
        "typedoc": "npx typedoc --out docs src/main.ts --exclude ./node_modules/**",
    }
```

I run it

```
npm run typedoc
```

And get a error:

> Unexpected token } in JSON at position 920 while parsing near '...node_modules/**"

How do I solve it?

Comment: Did you try running it without extra arguments? It should already exclude node_modules

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes I did.  npx typedoc --out docs src/main.ts gives the same result

Comment: Check out my [template](https://github.com/patrickroberts/template) project for an example. There's a `typedoc.json` in which I store most of the config options, and in `package.json` I basically just have `"docs": "typedoc src/index.ts"`. By the way, I also notice a trailing comma in your JSON, that could be the issue.

Comment: Do you not need to put the excluded expression between quotes? `'**/node_modules/**'`